# Reading character by character with android shell (mksh)

Tags: android, shell, text, ksh

Sorry if the question is easy. I am kind of a beginner in shell scripting, and I need to write a script which will work on a text file on a machine which mksh installed, but no working version of sed or most gnu utilities or compatible.

There is also no version of dos2unix installed.

The script receives a file which is dos formatted, but is quite simple in the kind of characters it contains (only letters and numbers, lenght of each line below 20 characters, few than 1000 lines), and it reads the file character by character adding the character to a "line" variable. When it reaches a carriage return it prints the line. Usage will be sh script.sh file.txt > newfile.txt.

The script does not work as intended and I am not really sure why:

```
#!/bin/sh

riga="";

nomefile="$1";

while IFS='' read -r -n1 carattere; 
    do 
        if [[ $carattere !=  *$'\r'* ]]; then
           riga="${riga}carattere";
        elif [[ $carattere == *$'\r'* ]]; then
            print "${riga%$}";
            riga="";
        fi    



done < "$nomefile"
```

This is the output of the script as originally written:

```
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
caratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecaratterecarattere
```

I read the excellent man pages of ksh at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh and modified the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

#!i=0
#!
riga="";

nomefile="$1";

while IFS='' read -r -n1 carattere; 
    do 
        if [[ $carattere !=  *$'\r'* ]]; then
           riga="${riga}$carattere";
        elif [[ $carattere == *$'\r'* ]]; then
            print "${riga%$}";
            riga="";
        fi    



done < "$nomefile"
```

The output is similar to what I intend, but blank lines are inserted between printed lines:

```
ID

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8
```

Comment: You can't use `[[ ]]` in a script running with `sh`, it only knows `[ ]`. Furthermore, you seem to have the redirection the wrong way around; use `< "$nomefile"` to read from that file. Are you limited to sh, or is Bash available?

Comment: The script runs in mksh, which is the only shell in the system. The [[ ]] are correctly interpreted by this particular shell, as I have another script where I use those (and this script did not run using single brackets). You are right about the redirection, I am correcting this.

Comment: Oh, okay. Your question says "Bourne shell", which is an ancient shell not really used anywhere any longer, you should probably clarify that and add at least the `ksh` tag instead of `sh`.

Comment: I clarified the platform and changed the tags as suggested. The reference to bourne shell and the sh tag was intended, as I thought I would be safe sticking with sh compatibility (as opposed to using bash only syntax): your comment about the double brackets made me think this is not the case (I think the double brackets won't be interpreted by bourne shell as you wrote, so mksh is not really compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after more reading of the ksh man pages and some tests, I found out what wasnt working. The first version of my script did not correctly append the characters I read to the *riga* variable, because I did not use a substitution ($) to append the *carattere* variable.

The second version worked as intended, but did not take into consideration the fact that dos files terminate lines with CRLF: I was thus checking for the \r character, and this meant the \n character was added to my *riga* variable. I modified the first if condition to check if the character is different from \n too.

Then an additional problem in my script was that, in the structure of files I want to convert, there are n lines and the last line is not terminated. This means my script would not write the characters of the last line in the *riga* variable, but it would not print the last line. I solved this adding a print instruction after the while cycle, using the -n parameter to avoid printing a newline after the string.

The final version of the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

#!i=0
#!^M
riga="";

nomefile="$1";

while IFS='' read -r -n1 carattere; 
    do 
        if [[ $carattere !=  *$'\r'* ]] && [[ $carattere !=  *$'\n'* ]]; then
           riga="${riga}$carattere";
        elif [[ $carattere == *$'\r'* ]]; then
            print "${riga%$}";
            riga="";
        fi    



done < "$nomefile"

print -n "${riga%$}";
```

Thanks to Benjamin whose comments put me in the right direction to solve my problem.